# Google indexing page even when there are no links to it

Tags: google-chrome, search, web-crawler, google-crawlers

The google indexed one of my pages, even there are no (I mean NONE) links to that page from anywhere (its a secret project and only 3 peopels know about it), but if I try to google its title, its in the results clearly indexed.

Does somebody know they did it? My theory is Google Chrome input when you go to the page, it just saves it to DB and crawls it.

Are there some pages talking about that? I tried to google it, but did not find anything.

Thanks.